# Android Webview: Is there a way to know what the previous URL is?

Tags: android, webview, back, browser-history

Is there a way to access the history so that I know what URL the user is visiting when they hit the back button (which calls WebView.goBack())?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is probably the method you're looking for: [`WebView.copyBackForwardList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#copyBackForwardList%28%29)

Answer (score 28):

```
String historyUrl="";
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewContent);
WebBackForwardList mWebBackForwardList = myWebView.copyBackForwardList();
if (mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex() > 0) 
    historyUrl = mWebBackForwardList.getItemAtIndex(mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex()-1).getUrl();

// Previous url is in historyUrl
```

Comment: eldy, put a semi colon at the end of the first line