# CustomWebViewRenderer DownloadManager issue with CopyBackForwardList

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I´m still learning android, I'm creating a hybrid app using this [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967929/xamarin-webview-webpage-cant-download-files-msecurityinputmethodservice-is-null).
All works fine, but when i finish downloading a file i cant go back, I'm trying to use copyBackForwardList Method but im not sure how to convert Xamarin.Forms.WebView to Android.Webkit.WebView to use CopyBackForwardList and use this other [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813914/android-webview-is-there-a-way-to-know-what-the-previous-url-is)

I'm trying something like this

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackButtonPressed();

        String historyUrl = "";
        int i = 0;
        WebBackForwardList mWebBackForwardList = (Android.Webkit.WebView)browser;
        if (mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex() > 0)
        {
            while (i < mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex())
            {
                historyUrl = mWebBackForwardList.getItemAtIndex(mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex() - ++i).getUrl();
                if (historyUrl != null)
                {
                    browser.Source = historyUrl;
                    Content = browser;
                }
            }
        }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Actually what i really want to do is fix the go back button. It works, but it stop working when i download a file ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the native controls it is done through custom renderers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: Actually what i really want to do is fix the go back button. It works, but it stop working when i download a file ...

Answer (score 0):

Have You considered this can be an issue related to Android's Activity life cycle? Once You have referred to the problem after downloading a file, and from the reference You have provided - by downloading the file, the Activity containing the WebView is not the foreground one anymore. So, I would like to suggest the following code (sorry for using Java here):

```
// ... 

private WebView browser;
private Bundle bundle; 

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // ...

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        browser.restoreState(bundle);
    }
    else
    {
        browser.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"); // e.g.
    }

    // ...    

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    bundle = new Bundle();
    browser.saveState(bundle);

}

// ...
```

The purpose of this code stands for saving the WebView object (browser) state when the main Activity exits the foreground, by saving its state within the Bundle (bundle) object.

Comment: i think is correct your diagnosis is ok, but in the answer you are using android native, im sill investigating how do the same with xamarin webview. i found the next https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/saving-state

Comment: I have been looking at this documentation on Activity Lifecycle [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/) and at this documentation on WebView [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.webkit.webview?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) and it may be a matter of implementing the above suggestion within the Xamarin scope.